# Authorize file write as administrator in Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, authorization

In my Cocoa application I need to write out a plist to a privileged location, so I was looking into the Security framework.  I have the code below, which does seem to properly pop up the dialog box asking for an administrator password, and I do see myself hitting the 'success' block.  However, I'm missing two pieces here:

1. How do I execute the writeToUrl:atomically: with those uplifted privs?
2. How do I put the privs back to what the user originally had?

Here's the method I'm using:

```
- (void)writePreferences:(NSDictionary *)prefs url:(NSURL *)url {
    AuthorizationRef auth = NULL;
    OSStatus authResult = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &auth);
    if (errAuthorizationSuccess != authResult) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't create authorization object, error %d", authResult);
        exit(-1);
    }

    @try {
        AuthorizationItem item;
        item.name = "com.gargoylesoft.FolderWatch.writePrefs";
        item.valueLength = 0;
        item.value = NULL;
        item.flags = 0;

        AuthorizationRights requestedRights;
        requestedRights.count = 1;
        requestedRights.items = &item;

        AuthorizationRights *grantedRights = NULL;
        authResult = AuthorizationCopyRights(auth,
                                             &requestedRights,
                                             kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,
                                             kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed,
                                             &grantedRights);

        if (authResult == errAuthorizationSuccess) {
            [prefs writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
        }

        AuthorizationFreeItemSet(grantedRights);
    } @finally {
        AuthorizationFree(auth, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults);
    }
}
```